# SetWidth() and SetHeight() in vtkActor2D causes a crash after a rendering call

Tags: c++, vtk, qvtkwidget

I'm trying to overlay text on an image in vtk when a certain button is clicked. I use a `vtkTextActor`, `vtkTextRepresentation`, and `vtkTextWidget` to achieve this.

Here is my code:

```
// set up actor
textActor->SetInput(label.toStdString().c_str());
textActor->GetTextProperty()->SetColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

// set location of widget
textRepresentation->GetPositionCoordinate()->SetCoordinateSystemToWorld();
textRepresentation->GetPositionCoordinate()->SetValue(200,200);

// set up widget
textWidget->SetInteractor(imageInteractor);
textWidget->SetRepresentation(textRepresentation);
textWidget->SetDefaultRenderer(rend);
textWidget->SetTextActor(textActor);
textWidget->SelectableOff();

// render widget
rend->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
textWidget->On();
textWidget->GetTextActor()->SetWidth(vc[0]);
textWidget->GetTextActor()->SetHeight(vc[1]);
rend->GetRenderWindow()->Render(); // crash
```

If I comment out the `SetWidth` and `SetHeight` function calls, the program works fine and the text widget pops up rather small. However when I try to adjust the width and height of `textActor` it crashes during the render call. Note that `vc[0]` and `vc[1]` are relative to the viewport coordinate system, I calculate them in a different function.

I can adjust the width and height of `textActor` BEFORE the `textWidget->On()` call, and the widget will still pop up, but it ignores my width and height changes. I cannot seem to change the box dimensions programatically. Am I doing something wrong or is this a vtk bug?

Here is an example.  I'd like the text to appear bigger (changing the font size wont work, I think its because the actor itself is too small).

[image: example]

***UPDATE***
I have not figured out why its crashing or how to fix it. As a workaround, I've been adjusting the `Position2Coordinate` value in my `textRepresentation`. The rendering call seems to be readjusting my set values. Can anyone explain why or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's causing the crash, but I found a workaround. By using `textRepresentation->SetPosition(x1,x2)` and `textRepresentation->SetPosition2(width,height)`, I'm able to control the location and size of the widget. Its important to note that `SetPosition2()` is relative to `SetPosition()` meaning instead of a coordinate, the second position should be thought of a width and height. All of my values are in the Normalized Viewport coordinate system.